# Using a marquee progress bar correctly

Tags: c#, devexpress, controls

I have a [marquee progress bar control](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsMarqueeProgressBarControltopic) from devexpress. When I want to use it I usually do

```
myMarqueeBarControl.Stopped = false;

<Some code>

myMarqueeBarControl.Stopped = true;
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to use this control (or generally controls like this) without wrapping a piece of code between start and stop statements. I dont want my code bloated with these. Any ideas ?

Comment: is the code the same all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the interface to a class isn't what you want, wrap it into your own class.

You could maybe write a small `IDisposable` class that takes your control within the ctor and sets the state back on a dispose. In that case you could wrap your code into a using statement.

Here is some example wrapper code:

```
public class MarqueeWrapper : IDisposable
{
    private MarqueeControl _Source;

    public MarqueeWrapper(MarqueeControl source)
    {
        _Source = source;
        source.Stopped = false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        source.Stopped = true;
    }
}
```

And here is how you can use it:

```
using(var wrapper = new MarqueeWrapper(myMarqueeBarControl))
{
    // Some code...
}
```

That's just one idea. Maybe you have another way in your mind, but then simply write a small wrapper class and use it like you desire and let it do the dumb work for you.

Comment: VUNDABA !!!! (probably completely wrong ...) But loved the idea ... I'll be using it in the future ...